# How to Check if Array of Arrays Already Has value

Tags: arrays, swift

Hey I'm trying to figure out if I can look inside a variable that has array's inside its array and if we already have that value then print yes or no.

Code:

```
   var array = [[String]]()

   array.append(["John Allen", "150lb", "6.0ft"])
   array.append(["John Micheal", "150lb", "6.0ft"])
   array.append(["John Carlos", "200lb", "6.2ft"])

   if array.contains(["John Allen", "150lb", "6.0ft"]) {

        print("yes")

       } else {

        print("no")

    }
```

If we have a index/array that has John Allen for the first slot 150lb for the second slot and 6.0ft for the third slot then print yes.

Comment: It try's to make me put contains(where: And it also gives me this error after that 'Contextual type '([String]) throws -> Bool' cannot be used'

Comment: if array.contains(where: { (item) -> Bool in item == ["John Allen", "150lb", "6.0ft"] }) { ... }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the question is about how to use `contains`, then do it like this:

```
var array = [[String]]()

array.append(["John Allen", "150lb", "6.0ft"])
array.append(["John Micheal", "150lb", "6.0ft"])
array.append(["John Carlos", "200lb", "6.2ft"])

if array.contains(where:{$0 == ["John Allen", "150lb", "6.0ft"]}) {
   print("yes") // yes
}
```